# Fill a column with fixed values based on the rows in the previous column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with columns A-C, C might have 20 or 200 cells, it changes so it can't be fixed, I want to have a macro that creates a Column D starting at D2, fills up all the way down to the end of column C, so if C has a total of 50 rows, D will have 49 but ending at D50 since it starts at D2.

So, how could I do this as an excel macro with VBA or manually? Thanks!

[image: This is how I want the before and after to be, it's the final part of a big macro I have been working on]

Comment: What do you want to fill the column D with? Sum or average of column C?

Comment: @Wizhi  D i just want "0.8" for every cell, literally just 0.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do it manually by writing the value and double-click in the cell corner to fill in values. It requires that the adjacent cell have values!

[image]

Or you can use a basic VBA code that do it for you. It check the last row in column C and fills column D.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Fill_in_values()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Set worksheet name

lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in Column C in Sheet1

ws.Range("D2", "D" & lrow).Value = "0.8" 'Fill from D2 to last row.

End Sub
```